# Setting precision on std::cout in entire file scope - C++ iomanip

Tags: c++, cout, iomanip

I'm doing some calculations, and the results are being save in a file. I have to output very precise results, near the precision of the double variable, and I'm using the iomanip setprecision(int) for that. The problem is that I have to put the setprecision everywhere in the output, like that:

```
func1() {
cout<<setprecision(12)<<value;
cout<<setprecision(10)<<value2;
}
func2() {
cout<<setprecision(17)<<value4;
cout<<setprecision(3)<<value42;
}
```

And that is very cumbersome. Is there a way to set more generally the cout fixed modifier?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for [cout.precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/) ?

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 you'll be able to use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) which gives you shortest decimal representation by default, so you won't loose precision even if you don't specify it manually. For example:

```
std::cout << std::format("{}", M_PI);
```

prints

```
3.141592653589793
```

If you need a fixed precision you can store it in a variable and reuse in multiple places:

```
int precision = 10;
std::cout << std::format("{:.{}}", value, precision);
```